# How to resolve the error "Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean" in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Getting Fatal error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in
> /customers/d/8/0/csgotail.com/httpd.www/bot-withdraw.php:12 Stack
> trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> /customers/d/8/0/csgotail.com/httpd.www/bot-withdraw.php on line 12 in
> this code.

```
<?php
include 'default.php';
$db = getDB();

# Get bot inventory
$bot64Id = '76561198252557804';
$botInventory = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=292292076&token=j4qmPUCn"), true);
$rgInventory = $botInventory['rgInventory'];

# Get current pot
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM currentPot');
$currentPot = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo jsonSuccess(array('rgInventory' => $rgInventory, 'currentPot' => $currentPot));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error means means that your query is the issue. check your database call or sql query.

"An empty array is returned if there are zero results to fetch, or FALSE on failure. " from http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM currentPot');
if($stmt){
    $currentPot = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Check if the query executed or not before using the function `fetchAll()`. Your query probably returned nothing, so, `$stmt` is `false`, and so its saying `boolean`.